# Hide/Show floating action button during FragmentTransection

Tags: android, floating-action-button, fragmenttransaction

I have this code for open some Message Fragment.

```
private void openMessage(int position) {
    MessageRecord item = data.get(position);
    item.setIsRead(true);
    item.save();
    List<MessageRecord> tmp = new ArrayList<>(data);
    updateScreen(tmp);

    MessagesActivity2 parentActivity = ((MessagesActivity2) context);
    parentActivity.fab.hide();
    FragmentTransaction ft = parentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    MessageFragment fragment1 = MessageFragment.newInstance(item);
    ft.add(R.id.frame, fragment1);

    ft.commit();

}
```

And this line hides my fab.
    parentActivity.fab.hide();

But I can't figure out how to reopen my FAB after I press Back button and return to the view of the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed()` in the activity and inside check if the fragment is null or not as per your requirement, then hide your `FAB`.

Comment: That was easy! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding FAB on your Activity directly,add FAB on a fragment(FABFragment) and add another fragment(MessageFragment) for your message.

So whenever you want to show MessageFragment replace the FABFragment using following code:

`MessageFragment fragment1 = MessageFragment.newInstance(item);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment1);`

To communicate between your fragments use interfaces(https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)